# Server throws Forbidden on second ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, tomcat, csrf-protection

Tomact server with Spring 4 MVC inside, CORS setted, CSRF setted, allowed `GET,POST,PUT,DELETE`.

When I send Ajax `PUT` using with jquery for first time - server response `200 OK`, but when I send same request for the second time - I got `403 Forbidden`.
In every request CSRF headers present in request.

I don't know why but when I reload page, I can send request for first time again, and then it fail with 403